# New to Mac Platform, Trying to get back to default python install

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I've been trying to follow [this blog post](http://www.dx13.co.uk/articles/2009/10/23/MacPython-24-to-Default-Python-on-Snow-Leopard.html) to get my python version back to the snow leopard default.  I have followed the first two steps without a problem but am lost when it comes to 3 and 4.  I installed Python 2.6.4 but I assume the instructions are pretty similar.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 3:

`sudo rm /usr/local/bin/python`

Step 4:

`ls ~/.bash_profile.pysave`

If the file exists:

`rm ~/.bash_profile && mv ~/.bash_profile.pysave ~/.bash_profile`

You will probably want to close your shell / Terminal and open a new one at this point. Run Python and see what it tells you.

Comment: it tells: "python: posix_spawn: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No such file or directory"

Comment: Wow. That's all kinds of messed up right there. Did you actually delete or overwrite Python?... because that's all I can think would cause that error message. You can always drag & drop the Python framework from another running Mac... then run Disk Utility and update permissions.

Comment: @Pesilence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212270/python-asks-for-older-paths-on-mac-after-deleting-duplicate-python-installation/18099233#18099233

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that Snow Leopard ships with a buggy IDLE. You will not be able to create a new document with it. If you will use another editor, it may not bother you. I a working with  the following version:

Python 2.6.4 (r264:75821M, Oct 27 2009, 19:48:32)